# invalid file name in matlab when using file split

Tags: matlab

here jj will be the value of FN, but the trouble is iam getting a error message

??? Error using ==> fopen
Invalid filename.

```
DirName  = 'Samples\mattest\jj';
FileName = split('\\',DirName);

[a,b] = size(FileName);
FN = FileName(b);

file_1 = fopen(FN,'w');
```

split method was found at 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4873

Doesnt the code seem correct ? Could someone please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

The 1st argument to [FOPEN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html) should be a file name (if the file is locatied in current working directory) or full path to the file.

Why are you splitting the path? Is `jj` is the name of a file or a directory? You cannot use FOPEN for a directory.

To split a full path to a file to directory name, file name and extension it is better to use MATLAB's [FILEPARTS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fileparts.html) function.

For splitting a string you don't need special split function. Build-in REGEXP can help:

```
parts = regexp(dirname, '\\', 'split');
```

Comment: i found the problem , the reason for getting this error is because that the FN string contains two illegal characters '. Does anyone know how to remove them ?

Comment: Again try to use REGEXP. It shouldn't give you illegal characters.

Comment: How have you discovered illegal characters? Where they come from? Why do you think strrep does not work?